# Protected Access Level in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I make protected (like in ruby) variable or function in Swift? I know Swift has only 3 levels but nonetheless is it possible?

**Access Levels**

> Swift provides three different access levels for entities within your
>   code. These access levels are relative to the source file in which an
>   entity is defined, and also relative to the module that source file
>   belongs to.
>
> - Public access enables entities to be used within any source file from
>     their defining module, and also in a source file from another module
>     that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when
>     specifying the public interface to a framework.
> - Internal access
>     enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining
>     module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You
>     typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s
>     internal structure.
> - Private access restricts the use of an entity to
>     its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the
>     implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.
>
> Public
>   access is the highest (least restrictive) access level and private
>   access is the lowest (or most restrictive) access level

Currently I see only one solution - write parent class with private modifier and children class in single file but it's kind of painful.

Comment: There was a Swift Blog entry explaining the rationale for this. It seems not to be on Apple's website anymore, but you can still read it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150810115840/https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11.

Comment: @MartinR it is still on Apple Swift blogs, see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby's point of view, it may be important. However in Swift, neither it is useless, nor it is a matter of the language.

Swift language is primarily based on modules when it comes to access levels. It even has `public private(set)` variables, which is much needed in Objective-C (causes boilerplate).

Answer (score 11):

Swift prefers to not use `protected`. You can read the reasons here [Access Control and protected](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11)

> In contrast, protected conflates access with inheritance, adding an entirely new control axis to reason about. It doesn’t actually offer any real protection, since a subclass can always expose “protected” API through a new public method or property. It doesn’t offer additional optimization opportunities either, since new overrides can come from anywhere. And it’s unnecessarily restrictive — it allows subclasses, but not any of the subclass’s helpers, to access something.

Comment: "Since a subclass can always expose “protected” API through a new public method or property." this is just a stupid rationale. Well my private method can also be exposed by some public method. Then why we have private?!

Answer (score 5):

There's no equivalent to `protected` in Swift where only subclasses have access to the method.  Personally, I don't miss it.

In Swift (as Objective-C) there is far less emphasis on subclassing than other languages.  If you find you have a set of methods that you want to be protected, it is probably better to factor them out as a delegate.

Comment: @Arsen What do you mean by "secretly"?

Comment: I would like to hear more about how to factor them out as a delegate.

Comment: @DavidRector If you have a load of protected methods that must be implemented by a subclass, put them all in a protocol and have a delegate property which is an object that implements the protocol. Then your main class calls methods on the delegate instead of the protected methods.

Comment: That's not an option. I have an `NSOperation` subclass and I want to expose a method to `finish` the operation. Only subclass should be able to call it. Doing so from the outside would cause an internal state inconsistency and potentially wreck my entire app. Delegate _is not an option_, **protected** method is. It looks like my only solution besides ignoring the problem is to pass around closures that call into private methods.

Comment: @BenAffleck `NSOperation` is an Objective-C class. Even private methods don't really have meaning with Objective-C classes. I think your best option is to make the method more robust so calling it from outside of the class doesn't damage the state.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3.0 not cantains protected modifier. In our sdk we use internal(set) modifier that approve set operation only in sdk project.

```
private var _authorized : Bool = false
public internal(set) var authorized : Bool
{
    get
    {
        return _authorized;
    }
    set
    {
        _authorized = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: you really could just use `public internal(set) var authorized : Bool` instead of splitting the two properties and have the getter and setter for the public one

Comment: How is this even related?