# Swift: How to make a overriden function that's not available for call

Tags: swift, inheritance

I would like to create a function that must be overriden by subclass, but that function is not available for use.  For example.

```
open class Animal {
  func favFood() throws -> String {
    throw UnImplementedError()
  }

  func eatFood() throws {
    print("Yum, I love \(try favFood())")
  }
}

class Cat: Animal {
  override func favFood() throws -> String {
    return "fish"
  }
}

let cat = Cat()
try cat.eatFood()  // I want this method to be available
try cat.favFood()  // I want to prevent people from using this method
```

I saw a solution that uses fileprivate.  But in my case, it doesn't make logical sense to keep all the overriden method in the same file.  I also want to allow any module to override the Animal, but force them to implement the favFood()

[Allowing a function to be accessed/overriden by subclass but not any other class in same module in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049047/allowing-a-function-to-be-accessed-overriden-by-subclass-but-not-any-other-class)

I guess, one possible sol'n is to create an initializer in the Animal class to force the subclass to pass the "favFood" as a parameter.  But, that could get messy if I have many functions that need to be overriden.  Or the method must be called after the object is created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protected Access Level in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603179/protected-access-level-in-swift)

Comment: This would violate [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), such that a subclass must always be able to do everything its superclass can do (a type must always be substitutable for its supertype). Specifically, what do you expect to happen for `(cat as Animal).favFood()`? How could the compiler know to prevent it? Should it crash at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a perfect solution, I think you can do this with `@available(*, unavailable)`.  So my example above with the Cat class, it would change to:

```
class Cat: Animal {
  @available(*, unavailable)
  override func favFood() throws -> String {
    return "fish"
  }
}
```

This means that the responsibility falls on the subclass to prevent it from being used, but it's better than nothing.